# How to save multiple records with one query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have over 100,000 records in my hand, as `Array of STD Objects` (can be converted to `Array of Arrays` or `Array of Eloquent Models`).

How to store all of them in the database with **1 query**.

*If you are wondering I got these data from another database connection to save them into my database.*

Of course I can build each Eloquent model and call the `save()` function but this will take a lot of time and is not recommended anyway.
I tried the `insert()` on the model passing to it an Array of Eloquent Models, but didn't worked for some reasons!!

So what options do I have, other than generating the raw SQL query?

I am using Laravel 4.2 here.

Comment: As per Taylor Otwell: "Honestly just use the query builder for this. Will be much more efficient and makes more sense."
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295

Comment: I think there is also a function defined `savemany` in laravel, it would be good if you share some of your code.

Comment: @DavidStromberg if you can share some code that demonstrates how to do it with the Query Builder, or what functions to use that would be very helpful.

Comment: @AnshulMishra the `saveMany` is when you have relations you can save them al l together, it works very well. But that's not my case. And the code is very complicated (it's not mine) :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `insert()` method on the Model, but it must be an array of arrays. You also need to make sure that all your array entries have the same keys. If an entry is missing a key, the inserted values for that entry may be off.

You mentioned you're starting with an array of objects. You can convert this array of objects to an array of arrays, and then use the insert statement.

Assuming you have a `Book` model:

```
$data = [
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Title 1',
        'author' => 'Author 1',
        'publisher' => 'Publisher 1',
    ],
    (object) [
        'title' => 'Title 2',
        'author' => 'Author 2',
        'publisher' => null, // make sure key exists; use null value;
    ],
];

// Convert your objects to arrays. You can use array_walk instead,
// if you prefer to just modify the original $data
$arrayData = array_map(function($value) {
    return (array) $value;
}, $data);

// do the insert
$success = Book::insert($arrayData);

// view last query run (to confirm one bulk insert statement)
$log = DB::getQueryLog();
print_r(end($log));
```

I don't know the details about your existing data, so you may need some more complicated logic to ensure the arrays are correct, but the above is a gist of what should work.

### Edit

When doing a bulk insert like this, you also need to pay attention to the `max_allowed_packet` MySQL variable. The default value for this variable is 1 MB, so if you generate a SQL statement larger than 1 MB, you will get an error. [max_allowed_packet documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

So, if this is your issue, you can either up the `max_allowed_packet` MySQL variable so that it is large enough to contain your entire SQL statement, or you can break your insert into chunks small enough to fit under the current `max_allowed_packet` size (default 1 MB).

An example of chunking your inserts:

```
// assume $arrayData is your array of arrays

// you can come up with some fancy algorithm to determine your optimal
// chunk size if you want. 
$size = 100;

$chunks = array_chunk($arrayData, $size);
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    Book::insert($chunk);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do but didn't worked (apparently it was because of the size of the data). This might be a valid method. However my data is huge and this doesn't work with it (speaking of over 200,000 records at some tables).

Comment: @MahmoudZalt I have updated my answer. I'm assuming you were running into a "packet too large" issue. If this is not the error you were having, what "didn't work"?